# Bash/Expect Time-Out on Password returns 0

Tags: bash, expect

I have a bash script which contains the following snippet:

```
function test_sftp_connection() {
expect << EOF
log_user 0
spawn -noecho sftp -P $SFTP_SERVER_PORTNUMBER $SFTP_SERVER_USERNAME@$SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME
expect "password:"
send "$SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\r"
EOF

  # Check the exit status of the expect command
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to connect to the SFTP server."
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

My current understanding is that 'expect "sftp>"' does what it says it does; it expects an sftp> prompt. So if a wrong password was entered by the script, and you are asked to enter the password again; this is obviously not the same. So I expect it to stop executing; returning with a non-zero status code.

Unfortunately, it does not do this. Instead, it times out with status code 0. I don't understand why it does this or how I can solve this. It would be much appreciated if someone knows how to deal with this situation.

Comment: I think because you have set "log_user 0" at the beginning of the expect block, which disables the display of output from the spawned process!

Comment: Not related to your problem (which has been answered by _Freeman_ anyway), but will perhaps bite you later: Shouldn't you have `return 1` instead of `exit 1`? An `exit` in a function is seldom a good idea.

Comment: I's a good suggestion. However, I tried this and the script does always returns 0 when using the return command. I don't know why. Maybe it has something to do with running an expect script inside a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed `log_user 0` to `log_user 1` to enable logging of output and I added an additional expect block to handle the case when the prompt is not `sftp>`,so in this case I exit with a status code of 1 using the `timeout` keyword!

check this out :

```
function test_sftp_connection() {
  expect << EOF > /dev/null
  log_user 0
  spawn -noecho sftp -P $SFTP_SERVER_PORTNUMBER $SFTP_SERVER_USERNAME@$SFTP_SERVER_HOSTNAME
  expect "password:"
  send "$SFTP_SERVER_PASSWORD\r"
  expect {
    "sftp>" {
      send "exit\r"
      expect eof
      exit 0
    }
    timeout {
      exit 1
    }
  }
EOF

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to connect to the SFTP server."
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Comment: After you send exit, you might want to `expect eof; exit 0` instead of `exp_continue`. I think the way it's currently written, you'll always exit 1

Comment: @glennjackman good point thnx a lot.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response; it does indeed solve the issue!

There's still two things bugging me:
- Why does expect not work like I thought it would?
- In my testing, I used a wrong password on purpose. It prints a bunch of lines before printing "Unable to connect to the SFTP server". I don't like this as it's going to clog up the logging.

Comment: @MaestroMaus to prevent the extra lines from being printed when using a wrong password, you can redirect the output to /dev/null, I will update the code for you!